# cURL local path

Tags: authentication, curl, asp-classic

I'm trying to use cURL to get past a login page, but in the process, it makes calls behind the scenes to local paths (i.e. it wants to get some file in `/Private/....asp` instead of `example.com/Private/....asp`), but of course these local paths don't exist on my server.  Is this a limitation of cURL or is there a way for me to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it bouncing you to another location?

Try the `-L` switch:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L

**Edit:**

The button click on the first page [1] is a POST to [2].
So I think what you want to do is to do that POST using curl (saving cookies with `-c`).  That ordinarily just redirects your browser to [3] but I think you want to save the cookie along the way, so do the first POST to [2] then GET [3], using `-c` again to save cookies but also `-b` with the same cookie file as you created when POSTing to [2].

When you GET [3] you will notice that the result is a page that uses javascript to auto-submit a form with some authentication values.  You're going to have to pull out these values, drop them in a file and then use them as `-d` (or `--data-urlencode`) POST data to [4]. Parsing out the values may be non-trivial, depending on your knowledge of e.g. perl. But nevertheless you can POST those values to [4] and use the same cookies as before, and that should land you on your login page [5].

Let me know how that works.

[1] `https://acadinfo.wustl.edu/` 
[2] `https://acadinfo.wustl.edu/redirectToWSPrivate.asp` 
[3] `https://acadinfo.wustl.edu/Private/WebSTAC.asp` 
[4] `https://login.wustl.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO` 
[4a] `https://login.wustl.edu/idp/Authn/UserPassword` 
[5] `https://connect.wustl.edu/login/wulogin.aspx`

**Another note:**
So it looks like even after you post to [4], your browser would ordinarily be sent to [4a] which then does yet another javascript redirect to [5].  So after posting to [4] you would have to manually GET [5] with a call to curl and the same cookies file you used all along.

Comment: I'm using the follow location option.  For more information, the page is https://webstac.wustl.edu and I'm just trying to get past the login button with cURL, to the place where you put in your username and password.

Comment: So there's a bunch of javascript redirects in that chain. Is it critical that you do this (get from https://webstac.wustl.edu/ to https://connect.wustl.edu/login/wulogin.aspx with a single call to curl?  I'm not sure if it's possible.  If you're willing to issue a few sequential calls to curl, I could give you some guesses. lemme know.

Comment: If I use multiple cURL calls, that would work too, it's just a question of getting past that page.